# Prove that a relation is a map from a set to its power set.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $S$ and $T$ be two sets. If $R$ is a relation of $S \times T$, then for each $t \in T$we
have the pre-image

$_{R}{[t]}=\{s \in S| sRt\} $

Which is a subset of $S$

Prove that the relation $\{(t,_{R}[t])|t \in T\}$ is a map from $T$ to the power set $\mathscr{P}(S)$  of $S$.

Moreover, show that, if $f:T \rightarrow \mathscr{P}(S)$is a map, then $R_{f} = \{(s,t)|s \in f(t)\}$is a relation on
$S \times T$ with $_{R_{f}}\textrm{[t]}=f$

I am not sure how to even start. Do I have to first show that the relation is a function first or is it obvious from the definition?

Comment: At the last you introduce notations like ${}_R[t]_1$ etc., which you have not defined.

Comment: It was my misunderstanding of the question. I wanted to show that the $t$ has a relation with a unique element but I realised that no matter the choice of $t$, $tR_{R}[t]$

Comment: If you have a subset $\{(a,\phi(a)):a\in A\}$ of $A\times B$ where for each $a\in A$, $\phi(a)$ denotes a well defined element of $B$ then this is (the graph of) a function from $A$ to $B$.